# Writing debug build only assertion function ignoring side-effects

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation

Today I discovered some of my assertion functions are still exist and being called in release build. Here's an example of my assertion function.

```
bool const isDebugMode()
{
    return false;  // Will be controlled by preprocessor flag.
}
void assertWithReason(bool const condition, std::string const reason = "")
{
    if (isDebugMode() and not condition)
    {
        abort();
    }
}
```

I think some side-effect in condition expression is preventing eliminating the assertion call.

For example,

```
assertWithReason(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
```

I expected this assertion call to be eliminated, but it is not. Because it is being executed before checking debug-build.

I am not sure how C++ handles this case, but as C++ is very strict language, it doesn't seem to be eliminated unless I put some special flag. Anyway, I intentionally wrote the assertions to be removed in release build.

Is it possible to write a function which is **surely** removed in release build in C++?
Of course I can use preprocessor macro, but I want to avoid using preprocessor macro as much as possible.

I am using Clang, and compiler specific extension (such as GCC attribute) is also fine.

Comment: Why would your assertion call be "eliminated"? It's still a normal function that is called. And the expression used for the first argument is always evaluated before the function is actually called. There is a reason assertions are mostly handled by preprocessor macros, as it allows you to bypass the normal "evaluate arguments before function call" rules.

Comment: In this particular case, I don't think the compiler SHOULD eliminate the call - since `glGetError` has side-effects - it resets the error status.

Comment: NB. your call to `assertWithReason` is actually incorrect - you're missing the reason. Using a macro and stringizing as in Mats' answer is just the best approach here IMO.

Comment: @Useless I fixed the bug in the example code.

Comment: Now you don't even have a reason to log :)  Seriously, get over your preprocessor allergy and go with Mats' answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I quite like using macros for this purpose. Yes, I know, Macros are **evil**, but just like knives (used wrong) are evil, they come in handy if you use them right.

```
 #define MY_ASSERT(x) do {\
       if (is_debug() && !x) assertFailed(__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, #x);\
     } while(0);
```

Now you can also show where it failed (`my_drawfunc.cpp: 34 : my_do_draw(): assertion failed: glGetError == GL_NO_ERROR` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can use lambda expressions. It is likely that constant propogation will make it so that is_debug is never evaulated, and even if it is, the lambda is not called.

```
class Debug { enum { is_debug = 1; } };

template <class F>
void assert(F f) { 
    if (is_debug && !f()) abort();
}

{
    int x = 6;
    assert([&]() { return x == 6; });
}
```

Comment: This works, but it gets quite awkward to write. `assert_with_reason([&]() { return glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR); });`